# Making an array of Xpath results in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xpath, web-scraping

I know this is very simple question, but I'm apparently terrible at coding and need a bit of advice as I just started using XPath.

I just used the Xpath function `$xpath->query("//a[contains(@id, 'title_')]/@href");` to grab a bunch of links. I'm wondering how I manipulate this data, such as store it into an array? I know how to call each part individually (ie: `$hrefs->item(0)->nodeValue;`) but beyond that I have no clue.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Why do you think you need an array? `$hrefs` will be a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/domnodelist) object, which you can `foreach` over if you wish. What is your intension when you say "manipulate this data"?

Comment: True. I just have no idea how to manipulate a Node list. I guess I'll do some research in to it. I basically am generating some links and then want to open the links later. I know how to do that with an array and not a NodeList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query method returns a [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/domnodelist). While this itself isn't an array, you can still iterate over it like an array. For example:

```
$values = array();
foreach ($hrefs as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
    $values[] = $node->nodeValue;
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Yeah. That's what I figured. Thanks a bunch